# How to intercept HTTPS traffic on machine without proxy?

Tags: windows, http, networking, fiddler

I need to develop an app that intercepts HTTPS traffic on the machine and change it.
One approach is to use a local proxy, like Fiddler works.

I also saw HTTP Debugger (https://www.httpdebugger.com/) which works in a similar way to Fiddler but say they don't use a proxy.

Do you know what technology HTTP Debugger are using in order to intercept HTTPS traffic without proxy?

Comment: The page of httpdebugger.com does not mention how it works, but I assume it works like a regular debugger and inject the relevant code for intercepting HTTP(S) into the process that makes the HTTP(s) calls. You can do something similar using [Frida](https://frida.re). However the code for capturing HTTP(S) calls is not included in Frida. And you need to develop own code for every HTTP library and SSL/TLS library. Hence the approach does not work in a generic way like Fiddler/a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using a pre-master secret key.

Here is an example with Wireshark: https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/

Wireshark using WinPcap https://www.winpcap.org/ network capture library to intercept traffic, so there is no proxy involved.

EDIT: I don't know how exactly works HTTP Debugger, but if there is no proxy the only way is to decrypt traffic on network level.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this out.

Comment: Wireshark allows decryption of SSL/TLS connections this way, but modification is impossible. My guess regarding HTTP Debugger is that it works like a classic debugger and modifies the application in-memory that makes the HTTP(S) calls. If you access the HTTP data before it gets TLS encrypted you have the plain text and can modify it.